# Ignoring Orientation

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

I am building a web application for iPhone. Since the application shows different content while in different orientations, the built-in animation between the two orientations animates the original content as well.

For better result, I would like to disable the animation between the portrait and landscape. Is there a way to do it for web app?

I have checked the `<meta>` tag but there is not a relevant one.

Thanks for any help!

Felix

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. The only option there is for handling orientation in using viewport.

From the documentation (found here: http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/appleapplications/conceptual/Dashcode_UserGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/Dashcode_UserGuide.pdf), it states:

> **Viewport** 
>   The values in this section control how users can view
>   your mobile Safari web application
>   when they use it on iPhone or iPod
>   touch. When users change the device
>   orientation from portrait to
>   landscape, webpages can get scaled to
>   fit the new screen orientation. The
>   two options for the Orientation value
>   are:
>
> ***“Adjust page width to fit.”*** When you choose this option, your web
>   application resizes (that is,
>   increases or decreases in width) when
>   the device orientation changes. This
>   option is generally recommended for
>   mobile Safari web applications,
>   because it enhances the user’s
>   perception of the web application as a
>   standalone application and not a
>   webpage.
>
> ***"Zoom page to fit.”*** When you choose this option, the width of your mobile
>   Safari web application does not change
>   when the device orientation changes,
>   but the scale does. In other words,
>   the content of your web application
>   will appear a bit bigger. You might
>   want to choose this option if your web
>   application has a complicated layout
>   that you don’t want to change in width
>   when the device orientation changes.

An example:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

Br,
Paul Peelen